# Export data as csv is not working in django

Tags: django, csv, django-views

I'm currently trying to export a csv file if the print button is clicked.

> The problem is the file which generated is not .csv file

However, the file content is retrieve the values which I need (I checked by changing type of file manually. Hereby I attached the result). 
Could anyone show me the mistakes? Or is it related to any requirement plugin?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

```
import csv

query_data = search_data(request,request.user.userid)   


if (request.method == 'POST'):
        if 'csvexport' in request.POST:
            data = csv_export(query_data)
            return HttpResponse (data,content_type='text/csv')
```

--

```
def csv_export (data):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    response.write('\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    writer.writerow([,'valData'
                     ,'value1'
                     ,'value2'])
    for rec in data:
        writer.writerow([rec['valData']
                         ,rec['value1']
                         ,rec['value2']])
    return response
```

--

```
def search_data(request,userid):
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = str("SELECT\n"
            " valData,\n"
            " MG0.valData as value1,\n"
            " MG1.valData as value2,\n"
        " FROM\n"
        " T_USER AS TU\n"

        " LEFT JOIN M_GENERAL AS MG0\n"
        " ON MG0.Cd='001'\n"

         " LEFT JOIN M_GENERAL AS MG1\n"
        " ON MG1.Cd='001'\n")

cursor.execute(query)
row = dictfetchall(cursor,)
return row
```

Comment: Can you add the file-content screenshot or something like that ?

Comment: ok @JerinPeterGeorge

Comment: Export CSV function should return the raw text, not httpresponse

Comment: So, What's the wrong in your csv file / screenshot? It's fine, right?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge please read again. the problem is the file which generated is not a csv file, but has no-type file (extension). the picture is just show the result if added its file extension manually.

Comment: I added an answer. Try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (request.method == 'POST'):
        if 'csvexport' in request.POST:
            return csv_export(query_data)
```